# Preserve $location.search () when changing URL in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS v1.3.15 I'm using $location.search to track some information that needs to survive location changes.  I.E. if the user is at Pending, and clicks on Giving, I want the user to go to Giving and have the search terms preserved:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/#/Pending?storeName=FunHouse

http://localhost:8080/MyApp/#/Giving?storeName=FunHouse
```

What are the commands to make that happen?

Comment: you can use localstorage

Comment: use `$location.path('/Giving')`

Comment: The links are all html a href="...".  So are you saying I should switch them to a ng-click or ng-href?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular [localStorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

You get the location url parameters:

```
var searchUrl = $location.search();
// => { storeName : 'FunHouse' }
```

which you can pass as a parameter to `localStorage` `set` function:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {  
   localStorageService.set('pending-url', searchUrl);     
});
```

Then when you are on the `giving` url you get the search terms saved to location storage and append to the url. If you have already some parameters appended to the url you need to clear them. You can do this by setting the current url to `$location`.

```
$location.url($location.path());
```

---

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {  
   var url = localStorageService.get('pending-url');     
   $location.search(url);
});
```